# How did 甚 + 至 compound to mean "even"?

Tags: etymology

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-chinese/even) translates 'even' as [甚至](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%94%9A%E8%87%B3), as can be substantiated on [ZDIC.net](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%94%9A%E8%87%B3). But what semantic notions underlie 甚, 至 with "even"?

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary).  I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- 甚 = extent
- 至 = to
- 甚至 = to the extent of (literal meaning)
- (甚至)殺人(也)做得出來 = (to the extent that) he will do killing (too) = (even) killing (too) he would do

The extended meaning of "even" in 甚至 is implied from the implied 也(too) in the [甚至 ... 也] structure

Note: the literal meaning of 甚至 (to the extent of) is as commonly used as "even". e.g. 甚至不吃不喝 (to the extent of not eating or drinking)